# How to obtain superimposed colors from 3 raster RGB in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay

I have 3 separate raster layers with binary values (1/0).

By assigning the 3 primary RGB colors to each of the layers, I would like to obtain a representation that expresses the overlap of the layers themselves with the derived colors, as in the diagram below.

I tried to reclassify the 3 layers by assigning the value 255 to the original 1 and the value 0 to the original 0, then I combined them into a single virtual layer by assigning a band to each of the 3 layers.

The result, however, is not what I expected, as shown in the first screenshot below.

Basically I get the white color where the 3 layers have overlap in the original value 1 (255) and the black where they have overlap in the original value 0 (0). However, I can't get the secondary colors cyan, magenta and yellow where only 2 layers overlap.

I can get the result I want by assigning one of the 3 RGB primary colors each to the 3 binary layers and using the `"Addition" Blending mode` in the `Rendering Layer`, as shown in the second screenshot. But in this way I'm forced to use a dark layer as background, to obtain pure secondary colors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I already tried to do what you explained, but I kept having problems.
However I realized that I had a problem with no data values on one of the 3 layers which was creating RGB rendering problems. Fixed the problem, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reclassify the original rasters, binary works just fine. `Build Virtual Raster` and `Merge` both works here, what is important to check *Place each input file into a separate band*. This will allow you to use the Multiband color renderer to achieve the desired end result.

Once you created the merged/virtual raster, open the `Layer Properties` window.

- Under *Symbology*, set the render type drop-down to *Multiband color*.
- Select a different band (1;2;3) for each of the red, green, blue render bands.
- Set the *Min* values to 0; and the *Max* values to 1 for each.
- From the *Contrast enhancement* drop-down, select *Stretch to MinMax*.

[image: Screenshot showing the described settings]

And the result:

[image: End result of color addition in QGIS]